# Taylor series expansion as constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, trigonometry, taylor-series

I'm trying to build a simple `sine` function using taylor series expansion that can be evaluated at compile time using C++14 `constexpr`. My code is compiling, but the compiler doesn't generate a constant.

`sine` is defined as follows:

```
template <int P, typename T = double> constexpr T sine(T x) {
    T result = x;

    for (int i = 1; i < P; ++i)
        result += power<T>(-1, i) * power<T>(x, 1 + 2 * i) / factorial<T>(1 + 2 * i);

    return result;
}
```

I can provide code for `power` and `factorial` if needed. They are trivial and also `constexpr`.

I'm calling `sine` from within a loop like this:

```
template <int N> void test(double *out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i] = sine<20, double>(i * M_PI / N);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the compiler can generate a set of results for `sine` and put them into `out` without actually needing to compute the taylor series. Instead the generated code executes `sine` as if it was any other non-`constexpr` function.

My compiler is clang from Xcode 7.2 compiling with `-O3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was expecting that the compiler can generate a set of results for
>   sine and put them into out without actually needing to compute the
>   taylor series. Instead the generated code executes sine as if it was
>   any other non-constexpr function.

For a `constexpr` function to be evaluated at compile time the following must apply:

- All of its input arguments must be constant expressions.
- Its result must be used in a constant expression.

The assignment in the `test`'s for loop is not a constant expression. Consequently, `sine` cannot be evaluated at compile time.

What you really want, is to statically initialize the elements of an array using `sine()`. Using a `std::array` and some helper machinery this is possible to do it as shown below:

```
#define r 0.01745329251

constexpr double factorial(int n) {
  double res = 1.0;

  for(int i(2); i <= n; ++i) res *= i;

  return res;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T power(T &&base, int const n) {

  if(!n) return 0.0;

  T res = base;

  for(int i(1); i < n; ++i) res *= base;

  return res;
}

template <typename T, int N = 5> 
constexpr T sine(T &&x) {
  T res = x * r;

  for (int i(3), sgn(-1); i <= N; i += 2, sgn = -sgn) {
    res += power(x * r, i) / factorial(i);
  }

  return res;
}

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<T, N> sine_array_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return {{sine(T{Is})...}}; 
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, N> sine_array() {
  return sine_array_impl<T, N>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec02c29d46107937)

Comment: Isn't the issue that the _argument_  to `sine`, `i * M_PI / N`, isn't a constexpr?

Comment: @Eric "All of its input arguments must be constant expressions." is not clear enough?

Comment: I was referring to _"The assignment in the test's for loop is not a constant expression"_. Is the assignment itself a problem here?

Comment: @101010 Sorry to bother you. I recognize the Taylor series in the code you've posted but not the `r` value. How does the `r` value help for the calculation of sine values? Was also wondering: is the `sine` code perhaps missing the use of `sgn` in the computation of `res`?